# What do these confusing lyrics mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, lyrics

What does the phrase,

> "I need to be with myself and center..."

mean?
 It's part of the lyrics of Fergie's *Big Girls Don't Cry*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She needs to center herself.

Expression meaning to focus

Example from a course in self healing: http://healingcurrents.blogspot.com/2010/03/what-does-it-mean-to-center-oneself.html

> Some popular cliches in spiritual
>   literature include "Center Yourself",
>   or "Find Your Center". Or, how about
>   "Navel Gazing" as a derisive term for
>   day dreaming, wasting time on
>   "non-productive" activities? What do
>   these terms mean? Is there a practical
>   meaning that escapes most people? The
>   human body is a bit like the planet
>   that we live on. It has a North pole
>   (the Crown Chakra at the top of the
>   head), a South pole (the Root Chakra
>   that spins straight down from just in
>   front of the tailbone), and an axis on
>   which the energy of our body spins. We
>   call this axis the "tube of light", or
>   "central vertical current".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused probably because you are expecting a list of things, therefore you might think that *center* is a noun in this phrase, which is wrong.

All you need to do is to realize that *center* is a verb in this case and thus the phrase can be formed as:

> I need to be with myself and focus ..."

Then, all should be pretty clear.